# Calling controller functions within module

Tags: angularjs

I have defined a function within my controller, which i want to call in a module. How is this possible?

The controller:

```
var App = angular.module('App',['ngResource','App.filters']);

App.controller('ExerciseCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.toggleOn = function (arr, id) {
        // Some code
    }; 

}]);
```

And the module:

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('someFilter', [function () {
    return function () {
        someArray = [];
        toggleOn(someArray, 1); // Wish to call this function
    };
}]);
```

I want to call `toggleOn` within the module.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve with this code? At a first glance, it doesn't seem like the "angular way" of doing things to call a scope function from within a filter. Even if you wished to do this, using angular services would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @ppa, its dummy code, i did not want to paste 900 lines of code in my question. I have a bunch of functions within my controller which i intended to use. Can you please explain how i should do this instead, if its not best-practice to call functions from a controller within the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, maybe something like this:

```
var App = angular.module('App',['ngResource','App.filters']);

App.service('toggleService', function(){
    var service = {
        toggleOn: function(arr, id){

        }
    };

    return service;
});

App.controller('ExerciseCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 'toggleService', function($scope, $http, toggleService) {

    $scope.toggleOn = toggleService.toggleOn;

}]);

angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('someFilter', ['toggleService', function (toggleService) {
    return function () {
        someArray = [];
        toggleService.toggleOn(someArray, 1); // Wish to call this function
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('someFilter', [function () {
    return function (scope) {
        someArray = [];
        scope.toggleOn(someArray, 1); // Wish to call this function
    };
}]);
```

And pass scope to filter

```
<span ng-controller="ExerciseCtrl">{{someFilter | this}}</span>
```

Comment: I forgot `var App = angular.module('App',['ngResource','App.filters']);` which i have defined. Check my edit